# Ionic : Change a page color according to origin of user

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I have two differents forms that display the same kind of items. So I think it would be better to use the same page to displays items from form A et from form B. But I would like the results list's background color to change according to the origin of the user.

Is that possible with Ionic or should I just do 2 differents pages to display the results of the search ?

Comment: Kindly post the code that you have tried so far, it will help people looking at this understand your problem and give the correct advice. Consider reading this [Handy Guide on Asking Questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updating your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one page. When page is loading you can use boolean type variable to switch colors. You can use *ngIf to switch  tags.